# Raw ftp hangs with big files

Tags: unix, ftp

I am using ftp command lines to send big video files (about 500 Mo) to 6 remote servers.

On 4 servers, everything goes well.
On 2 servers, my script hangs and the upload never completes.

It doesn't hang on the same files on the two servers, so I don't think it's a problem with the files.

Also, on one of the two servers, one video file is first sent successfully, but the script hangs on the second upload.

When I try to abort the script (Ctrl + C or Ctrl + D), nothing happens. I have to kill the terminal to end the script.

This is the code I'm using:

```
    ftp -v -n $server << EOF
    prompt
    quote USER $user
    quote PASS $password

    mput *.mov

    quit
EOF
```

What could be my problem?

Comment: Try using `ftp -i` or sending `prompt` or `prompt off` **after** login.

Comment: Do it hang in a middle of a file transfer? Or when starting/ending a transfer of some file?

Comment: @MarkSetchell this does not solve my problem.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl hard to say as I don't have much detail in the logs, but on one server it hangs after log message "150 Opening BINARY mode data connection for file.mov" and on the other after the message "Accepted data connection"